# Prove that an expression is not a prime

Tags: factoring

Today I had a math test, and there was one problem I couldn’t solve. Please help!

Prove that the following expressions are not prime numbers (there always exist a shorter beautiful
solution):

a) $2^{10}+5^{12}$

b) $65^{64}+64$

c) $989\cdot 1001\cdot 1007+320$

Comment: For B: write $65^{64} + 64 = (64 +1)^{64} + 64$ then use the binomial theorem.

Comment: None of these appear to have terribly natural prime factors.

Comment: @SeanRoberson, how does the binomial theorem help?

Comment: Given that this appeared in a math test, I'd love to see the "shorter beautiful solutions"!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For (a) and (b), we can use an [Aurifeuillean factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aurifeuillean_factorization):
$$
a^{4}+4b^{4}=(a^{2}-2ab+2b^{2})(a^{2}+2ab+2b^{2})
$$
Take $a=5^3$ and $b=2^2$. Then
$$
2^{10}+5^{12} = 4b^{4}+a^{4} = a^{4}+4b^{4}
= (a^{2}-2ab+2b^{2})(a^{2}+2ab+2b^{2})
= 14657 \cdot 16657
$$

Now take $a=65^{16}$ and $b=2$. Then
$$
65^{64}+64 = a^{4}+4b^{4} 
= (a^{2}-2ab+2b^{2})(a^{2}+2ab+2b^{2})
=
\small
10309258098174834118790766041058622855698420907745361328133
\quad\cdot
10309258098174834118790766041870898989955232237091064453133
$$

(c) is easier:
$$
x(x+12)(x+18)+320 = (x + 2) (x + 8) (x + 20)
$$
Now take $x=989$ and get
$$
989\cdot 1001\cdot 1007+320 = 991 \cdot 997 \cdot 1009
$$
(I was lucky that the first form I tried, $x(x+12)(x+18)+320$, factored so nicely!)

Comment: [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+65%5E64%2B64) cannot fully factor $65^{64}+64$... But it can factor the two factors given above.